# Definir parâmetros personalizados SoapClient PHP

Tags: php, web-service, soap, wsdl

Estou consumindo um webservice externo via PHP e o mesmo solicita autenticação de uma forma diferente, o login e senha tem que ser passado dentro do XML. Porém não estou conseguindo autenticar.

A chamada para o serviço está sendo criada da maneira abaixo.

```
public static function myFunction ($param){

        $soapClient = new \SoapClient('my_wsdl', [
            "trace"     => 1,
            "exception" => 0,
            'Login' => '*',
            'Senha' => '*'
        ]);

        return($soapClient->myService($param));
}
```

O serviço espera um XML conforme o abaixo:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:api="meu_endereco_api">
   <soapenv:Header>
   <Autenticacao>   
        <Login>*****</Login>
        <Password>****</Senha>
   </Autenticacao>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <api:minha_api soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <meu_parametro xsi:type="xsd:string">$param</meu_parametro>
      </api:minha_api>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

O serviço me retorna erro de autenticação:

> ```
> object(stdClass)[783]
>   public 'Parametro' => string 'ERRO NAO AUTENTICADO'
> ```

Alguém tem idéia de como enviar a requisição autenticada os parâmetros neste formato esperado?